# Spring cloud streams Kafka binder - Logging handler logging complete payload

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I’m using spring cloud streams with Kafka binder. I could see the payload is getting logged as failedMessage=GenericMessage[payload=[….etc. by LoggingHandler

In my case my payload has sensitive data which I don’t want to get exposed through logs. How can I avoid logging payload?

I see the LoggingHandler by default logs the payload only.

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks

I was checking if there is any flag that we can set, to exclude payload from logs. But I didn’t come across any.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom error handler as described here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling. That implementation could contain no code at all or anything you want. The main point is you would intercept default error handling.

I also believe that you can do something with logger configuration

Comment: I have tried the same from spring docs but it didn’t help. 
@Bean
public Consumer<ErrorMessage> myErrorHandler() {
 return v -> {
  // send SMS notification code
 };
}

Please note we consuming message in batch mode.

Comment: Your answer does not help in any way as we do not see your full application. If you want some assistance, please create a small reproducible sample and push it to github so we can tale a look